# Read and Write in the same file simultaneously in Java

Tags: java, string, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

What i want is to write a "string" that is in file A in file B if it does not already exist in file B, knowing that B is empty at the beginning

```
BufferedReader bfA=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A.txt"));
        BufferedReader bfB=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("B.txt"));
        BufferedWriter writerB=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("B.txt"));
        String line1,line2;
        boolean bool=false;
        while((line1=bfA.readLine())!=null){
            bfB=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("B.txt"));
            while((line2=bfB.readLine())!=null){

                if(line1.equals(line2)){
                    bool=true;}}

        if(bool==false){
            writerB.write(line1);
        }
        }
```

the problem is that if in the File A there's duplicate string

Comment: Why don't you just keep the lines that you already read in a Set, in memory? Unless your file is really large, this is way easier, and way faster, too.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: You create a HashSet<String>, in memory. Every time you read a line from A, you check if it's in the set. If it isn't, you write it to B. And you add the line in the set. So, no need to read B at each line.

Answer (score 0):

Following JB Nizet's answer, here some pseudo code

```
readerA, writerB = "", memory = ""
while(readerA.hasNextLine()){
       line = readerA.nextLine()
  if(line isNotPresent in memory){
       add line to memory 
       add line in writerB
   }
}
```

Hope this helps